# JQuery Mobile can't hold a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have Authlogic up and running in a Rails 3.1 app.  Everything runs A-OK.

When I use jQuery Mobile to try to 'mobilize' the app, the app can't 'hold' the session.  Meaning that on login, the app advances to the correct screen but the user isn't logged in.  Thus, no subsequent screens can be accessed.  Also, the 'after-login' url shows:

```
http://localhost:3000/user_sessions
```

and it should be

```
http://localhost:3000/mobiles
```

(I'm using a 'mobiles' controller to give me a /mobiles view where I put all the jQuery Mobile nested pages.)

I've narrowed it down to the jQuery script.  If I include it in the layout, the session can't be saved.  If I comment it out, the session is saved and everything works fine, but I lose the jQuery Mobile formatting / styling on the login form.

Here's the script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone having this problem too?

Comment: What does your form_for look like?

Comment: No really.  So I made a separate layout for the UN/PW screen that doesn't rely on JQM.  After login, it hands off to a separate layout that incorporates JQM.